# PLSQL insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

While reading bear in mind this is my first time working with PLSQL. So I'm trying to do an insert using a for loop like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2 AS 
CURSOR emailUsages IS
SELECT classCode, "ID"
FROM NJTELCOM
WHERE classCode = 'mailto';

BEGIN
FOR i IN emailUsages LOOP
  INSERT INTO NJTELCOMUSAGE 
  (classCode, "TELCOMID")
  VALUES 
  (i.classCode, i."ID");
dbms_output.put_line(i.classCode);
END LOOP;
NULL;
END PROCEDURE2;
```

While the code compiles, it's not working properly, and I don't even get output to the console(though I'm not sure if this is how to do it). I do have a column called id in the table NJTELCOM, calling it "ID" in the code was the only way I could achieve it not outputting an error. Not sure if that's what's causing it. Any help appreciated

Comment: calling it "ID" means that your select output the word ID and not the ID

Comment: You should also include the code used to call the procedure.

Comment: I'm just calling the procedure in SQL developer by pressing run. It just runs the procedure., sagi what should I name it then? I can't use id, it's a reserved word for plsql. And I can't change the column name, I do not own the table, only have access to the database

Comment: try replacing it with NJTELCOM.ID

Comment: If you're using SQLDeveloper, try going to sql worksheet, running `set serveroutput on` first, then `begin PROCEDURE2; end;`. DBMS output won't show in console unless you ask for it. Alternatively, go to View->DBMS Output, press big green plus and select your connection to view output in that window.

Comment: Also, run the query from your cursor in the worksheet. Perhaps it simply doesn't have any rows? And one more thing, you don't commit in your procedure, so if you won't immediately see data from another session, until you commit by hand.

Comment: Ah ok thank you this helps a lot, one more question, how do I commit?

Comment: You literally write `commit;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be written as a simply [INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2145074) statement:

```
INSERT INTO NJTELCOMUSAGE a (a.classCode, a.telcomid)
SELECT b.classCode, b.id
FROM NJTELCOM b
WHERE b.classCode = 'mailto';
```

Comment: This is a working solution, I was more or less just trying to learn cursors/for loops at the same time as doing this simple insert because I needed to add conditions to it, and more parts. 

TO MAKE IT WORK THOUGH, REPLACE b.id with b."ID"
id is a reserved word in plsql, to escape reserved words, just allcaps and surround with double-quotes. It works.

Comment: Cool! so you learned how to operate with `cursors` plus how to optimize the statement.